# how to filter records and get first record based on date using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am writing a Unit test where in i am passing array of two records and i want to send it to a method
which can filter the records and pass only a single record but i have tried to use FirstOrDefault but then it is throwing compile time error

here is my code

```
[Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var first = new Extra
            {
                Code = "P1",
                Cost= 100,
                DateFrom = DateTime.Parse("01 March 2022")
            };
            var second = new Extra
            {
                Code = "P3",
                Cost= 120,
                DateFrom = DateTime.Parse("01 April 2022")
            };
            var totalData= new[]
            {
                first,
                second
            };


            var value= GetExtraHandler.FetchExtras(totalData, DateTime.Parse("02 April 2022"));

            Assert.Equal(value, new[] { second });
```

Here is method which get called in GetExtraHandler

```
    public static IEnumerable<Extra> FetchExtras(Extra[] lvl, DateTime idate)
    {

        var data= lvl.Where(x => x.DateFrom < idate).FirstOrDefault();
        return data;
    }
```

So from this code when i build i am getting compile time error that method expects IEnumerable return type so if i use firstordefault it is throwing error.
I want a way so that if multiple records is less than datefrom i.e 02 April 2022 and in array which is passed is 01 April and 01 March then only 01 April record should get fetched.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` does not return an `IEnumerable<T>`, it returns a `T` (or `T?`).

Comment: i want only single record after filtering and want to put it in IEnumerable

Comment: Then return `new[] { data }` (and consider using `IReadOnlyList<T>` as the return-type instead of `IEnumerable<T>`), if `data is null` then return `Array.Empty<T>()`.

Comment: Use `query.Take(1)` for such task

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That depends if lazy-evaluation is appropriate or not.

Comment: Do `ToList()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`. Or do `Take(1).ToList()` to force only one record returned.

Comment: @Dai When would you imagine it would make a difference?

Comment: @NetMage If the returned `IEnumerable<T>` will be frequently re-iterated over by subsequent consumers (e.g. as the basis for a list-binding in WPF) then that's a good example of when it makes sense to first materialize it to some immutable collection type.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix FetchExtras method

```
public static IEnumerable<Extra> FetchExtras(Extra[] lvl, DateTime idate)
{
return lvl.Where(x => x.DateFrom < idate).OrderByDescending(x=> x.DateFrom).Take(1);
}
```

result

```
[
  {
    "Code": "P3",
    "Cost": 120,
    "DateFrom": "2022-04-01T00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `yield return` the item containing the latest `DateFrom` amongst those items that fulfill your condition:

```
public static IEnumerable<Extra> FetchExtras(Extra[] lvl, DateTime idate)
{
    yield return lvl.Where(x => x.DateFrom < idate).MaxBy(x => x.DateFrom);
}
```

[`.MaxBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby?view=net-6.0) is available from **.Net 6**.
`MaxBy( * )` can be replaced with e.g. `.OrderByDescending( * ).First()`.